# Upload image to facebook from input file

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

So, i'm trying top upload a simple image to facebook using the graph api.

The file is uploaded by an input type file

```
var file= $("#imagenesUpload")[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("source", file);
        FB.api("/me/photos", "POST", formData,
            function (response) {
              if (response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
            }
        );
```

But i'm always getting a `(#324) Requires upload file`

Also tried this with the same result

```
var file= $("#imagenesUpload")[0].files[0];
        FB.api("/me/photos", "POST", {"source":file},
            function (response) {
              if (response) {
                console.log(response);
              }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

On the official Facebook Developers site there is a post explaining how images should be set. Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

(*Check out Scenario 2*)

Comment: yeah, this method doesn't suit my needs.

As I stated, i'm working with JS, and the info here is with PHP, rather than that, they aren't even using the graph api, they are doing it directly with get method, which could lead to code injection and i don't want to deal with that, hence why i'm suing post and ajax as much as I can